Quantile maximization of the difference of random constrained quadratic optimization problems
I am interested in understanding the family of parametrized random variables defined by the pushforward map
$$
\lambda_x : \varepsilon \mapsto \underset{z_1 \in \mathbb{R}^n :\, h^T z_1 = 0, \; z_1 \geq -x}{\text{min}} \Vert Kz_1 - \varepsilon \Vert^2_2 - \underset{z_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n : \,z_2 \geq -x}{\text{min}} \Vert Kz_2 - \varepsilon \Vert^2_2 
$$
applied to a gaussian random variable $\varepsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0,I_m)$, with $K \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $h \in \mathbb{R}^n$ fixed and the parameter $x \in \mathbb{R}^n_+$ has non-negative coordinates. This arises in the context of Likelihood Ratio Test inversion in constrained inverse problems.
In particular, I aim to understand

Which $x \in \mathbb{R}^n_+$ maximizes the $(1-\alpha)-$quantile of $\lambda_x$, or narrow down which $x$ are possible maximizers. Maximization not over the whole space but over hyperplanes of the form $h^t x = m$ is also relevant to the statistics application I am working on.

Whether it is possible to bound the tail of the distribution, perhaps via the moment generating functions $\mathbb{E}(e^{t\lambda_x})$, or with inequalities involving other moments.


While the simulation of this random variable is straightforward via solving the convex optimization problems and the maximum quantile problem can be formulated as a chance-constrained optimization problem, I am generally wondering if any analytical techniques exist to give (possibly partial, i.e in specific cases of $h$ and $K$) answers to the questions above, or more generally which mathematical tools could help infer properties of this family of random variables.
